# Need help Understanding Dependency's Ionic Run Project

Tags: ionic-framework, project

Can anyone please guide me on how to fix this issue,

ionic info

---

Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

Please update your Node runtime to version  >=0.12.x
 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

---

Your system information:

Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.4.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.12
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v0.10.35
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62

---

Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

Please update your Node runtime to version  >=0.12.x
 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

---

Answer (score 1):

I had to set my path correctly in .bash_profile,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk
```

Then I had a conflict with another npm node install. it wasn't linked and had some permissions issues.
the dependency warnings where for deploy iOS,

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

and

```
npm install -g ios-deploy
```

You'll need to use --unsafe-perm=true if your on a OSX 10.11 El Capitan or higher like this,

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true
```

Then everything worked and ran smoothly for me, damn!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating Node and Cordova? Try to download and install the latest node version from [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then run `npm install -g cordova` from your terminal.

Comment: I did twice already and I still get this. I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong I'm running it in sudo too.

Comment: Interesting, installing an update usually clears up the issue for me. However see Warning with Cordova 6.1 for pointers on this issue

Answer (score 0):

update npm
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

I had the same problem before but it fixed it by updating npm then node then cordova

Comment: That's your own question :)